# MVC Roles without rolemanager

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I've used the asp.net identity to create my tables where it created the asp.net tables include `Roles` and `UserRoles` tables.
I can use `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` and also use

```
private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
db.Roles.ToList();
```

But I do not have `RoleManager` initialized inside web.config and still I can see these working fine. I can't seem to find the reason to use `RoleManager`. what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not missing anything. `RoleManager` is not getting initialised in `web.config` any more - this is a thing from the past.

There is `RoleManager` class that is available to be inherited and overridden when you need to. But under the covers it does exactly the same as you did with `ApplicationDbContext` only with a bit more "padding" and validation or role names.